# How can I print UPC-A objects for labels?

Tags: crystal-reports, clickonce, barcode, crystal-reports-2008

I have a Crystal Reports project that I am working on where I need to generate a label with UPC-A's.  After doing a bit of research, I've found that Azalea Software [offers a tool](http://www.azalea.com/upc/crystal-reports/) that is suppose to integrate barcode objects into your application.

I purchased the software from Azalea, followed all of their instructions and I can not get their software to work with my report.  I don't want to speak ill of Azalea, because their support has been great, but is anyone aware of a legitimate alternative for UPC-A barcode creatioon from within Crystal Reports 2008?

I don't mind purchasing another 3rd party API, I just need to be able to generate dynamic UPC-A images from the UPC-A numbers that I need to encode stored within my database.

Further information-- this is a label document that is printed from a ClickOnce published application that uses the Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010 runtime, and the Crystal Reports Document Viewer control to view and print these labels.

Comment: You have not said anything about the actual problem you are facing.

Comment: Simple-- I purchased the software that I linked to which should have generated the UPC-A objects.  It didn't and now I need an alternative.  How can I get a UPC-A on a Crystal Report document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [IDAutomation](http://www.idautomation.com/) for our barcoding.  Very easy to use when installed, you use it like a font on calculated barcode fields.  We use it mainly for Code-39 and Code-128 barcodes; though looking at the site it can make UPC/EAN codes too.  It also has a selection of sizes for each barcode, alongside the normal font resizing.

On our version you have to install the fonts on every client computer running the report locally; but only once on telnet servers etc.

Comment: FYI, I'm trying to be patient and wait for a response from Azalea support.  If they can't help me fix the problem, I will give IDAutomation a try.  I'll mark this as the answer once I verify that this works or if Azalea can help me out.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thank you!  IDAutomation's font package was just what I needed.